# CLISP tries to load weird directory in SLIME on Windows 10

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, clisp, slime

I've previously successfully installed Emacs + SLIME + SBCL on this machine.

I'm trying to install CLISP to work through some of the "Land of Lisp" examples that are CLISP specific.

When I start up SLIME with CLISP, it breaks when trying to load some SLIME files:

```
*** - OPEN: Directory #P"C:\\Users\\GUSTAV~1.BER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\" does not exist
```

I've explicitly set the `temporary-file-directory` to a fully expanded directory (`"C:\\Users\\Gustav.Bertram\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\"`) in `.clisprc.lisp` and I made sure that the variable is available at the point where the break happens.

The backtrace immediately after the error shows:

```
<1/164> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SHOW-STACK> 3
<2/157> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::PRINT-BACKTRACE>
<3/151> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::DEBUG-BACKTRACE>
<4/142> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT> 2
<5/139> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::BREAK-LOOP-2-3>
<6/135> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SYSTEM::SAME-ENV-AS> 2
<7/121> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::BREAK-LOOP-2>
<8/119> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SYSTEM::DRIVER>
<9/79> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::BREAK-LOOP>
<10/76> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION INVOKE-DEBUGGER> 1
<11/65> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION OPEN>
<12/57> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::ANNOUNCE-SERVER-PORT>
<13/54> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::START-SERVER-1>
<14/49> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::SETUP-SERVER>
<15/42> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK:START-SERVER>
<16/40> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION FUNCALL> 2
[38] EVAL frame for form (FUNCALL (READ-FROM-STRING "swank:start-server") "c:\\Users\\GUSTAV~1.BER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\slime.34812")
<17/35> #<SPECIAL-OPERATOR PROGN>
[34] EVAL frame for form 
(PROGN
 (LOAD "c:\\Users\\Gustav.Bertram\\AppData\\Roaming\\.emacs.d\\elpa\\slime-20170921.1000\\swank-loader.lisp" :VERBOSE T)
 (FUNCALL (READ-FROM-STRING "swank-loader:init"))
 (FUNCALL (READ-FROM-STRING "swank:start-server") "c:\\Users\\GUSTAV~1.BER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\slime.34812"))
Printed 17 frames
```

How can I figure out where the function call is coming from?

Comment: When you say you set `temporary-file-directory`, you mean the Emacs variable, right? Setting an Emacs variable in the CLISP initialization file (`.clisprc.lisp`) wouldn't do much good.

Comment: I know it’s annoying but you might want to just try doing this in a Linux vm. You’d hopefully find that less things go weird

Comment: @jkiiski I was following [these instructions](http://www.jonathanfischer.net/modern-common-lisp-on-windows/). Makes sense to me since Swank runs inside Emacs, and might look for such a variable.

Comment: @DanRobertson Several other people have had this problem, so I'm hoping in solving it we can fix CLISP and/or SLIME. If that doesn't work, I'll probably go the Linux VM route.

Comment: Swank is the part that runs in the CL. Slime is the part that runs in Emacs. Slime starts up cl and gets it to load swank then talks to swank (in the cl) using the slime/swank protocol. If `temporary-file-directory` is supposed to be set in CL then it needs to be in some package (like `swank`) but that package won’t be available until after your `clisprc` has run. I suspect however that it’s an Emacs variable so your setting of it should go in your `.emacs`.

Comment: Swank is the component that runs inside the Common Lisp image that Slime communicates with. That `(progn (load...) ...)` in the stack trace is what Slime passes to the CL to start up a server to talk with. You can see that the path is passed to the cl as a string, so it's coming from Emacs. Try setting the emacs variable `temporary-file-directory` in your init file or through `customize`.

Comment: @jkiiski @DanRobertson Hey, setting it in `.emacs` worked! One of you  want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the stack trace you can see that CLISP is evaluating the following:

```
(PROGN
 (LOAD "c:\\Users\\Gustav.Bertram\\AppData\\Roaming\\.emacs.d\\elpa\\slime-20170921.1000\\swank-loader.lisp" :VERBOSE T)
 (FUNCALL (READ-FROM-STRING "swank-loader:init"))
 (FUNCALL (READ-FROM-STRING "swank:start-server") "c:\\Users\\GUSTAV~1.BER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\slime.34812"))
```

This is what Slime passes to the Common Lisp after launching it in order to load Swank and start up a server to communicate with. You can see that the wrong path to the temporary file directory is passed as a string here, which means the directory must be resolved on the Emacs side. Emacs has a variable `temporary-file-directory` for this, which can be set in your initialization file, or via `customize`.